# How to create new column and assign values by column group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe,

```
df
uid    
 1     
 2      
 3
 ...
```

I want to assign a new column, with values 0 or 1 depending on the uid, which I will assign.

```
df
uid  new 
1     0
2     0
3     1
..
```

Comment: and how do you chose to which id to map the 0/1?

Comment: why do `1` and `2` both have `0` ?

Comment: share the relation b/w them also.. how `new` is dependent on `uid`!! like every `uid` divisible by 3 will assign 1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explain the underlying logic.

That said, there are many possible ways.

Considering an explicit mapping with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mapper = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}

df['new'] = df['uid'].map(mapper)

# or
mapper = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3]}

df['new'] = df['uid'].map({k:v for v,l in mapper.items() for k in l})
```

Or using a list of targets for the `1` with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and conversion to int

```
target = [3]

df['new'] = df['uid'].isin(target).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   uid  new
0    1    0
1    2    0
2    3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a correlation between `uid` and `new`, you can create a function to define the mapping between `uid` and `new`

```py
def mapping(value):
    new_value = value // 2
    return new_value
```

Then

```py
df["new"] = df["uid"].apply(mapping)
```

Or directly

```py
df["new"] = df["uid"].apply(lambda value: value // 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

from the relation of `3 uid's` I came up as a relation the `uid` which is divisible by 3 is assign to `1` else `0`. (Not sure the relation is correct or not as you have given only 3 values of `uid`)

you can apply `np.where()` -> `np.where(condition, x, y)` **if `condition` satisfy it assign value `x` else value `y`**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [1, 2, 3]})
df["new"] = np.where(df["uid"] % 3 == 0, 1, 0)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   uid  new
0    1    0
1    2    0
2    3    1
```